# Updating a value with jquery fails in iphone browsers in responsive web design

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

Am working on responsive web design, here i have two div elements with same id's.

one div will show in large screen and another div will show in small devices.

am updating a value in it with jquery, like $('#balance').val(500);

it is working fine in all android device browsers and web browsers except in iphone browsers?
i dont know why it fails to update div value in iphone browsers

**Note:** Does this cause problem two divs with same ID, but one is in none mode another one is in block mode while updating its value with jquery

```html
<span class="show-web">Available Now <span id="avlBal"></span></span>

<span class="show-mobile">Your balance <span id="avlBal"></span></span>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is working properly in all browsers? Having same ID in elements is the worst case scenario.

Comment: Is the `ID` common for both `div`'s ?

Comment: yeah, one div is in display none, another one is in block, so in all browsers working fine

Comment: yes, ID is common for both, but is in none another one is in block mode @d

Comment: ID must be unique !!!